# Working with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working with a stored procedure and I am trying to add the following information to the table:

```
Last Name: Beesley
First Name: Pam
Hire Date: Current Date
Birth Date: 12/30/1972
Title: Receptionist
```

This is what I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewEmployee (
     @LastName nvarchar(75)
     ,@FirstName nvarchar(50)
     ,@HireDate datetime
     ,@Birthdate datetime
     ,@Title nvarchar(30))

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Employees (LastName,FirstName,HireDate,BirthDate,Title)
    VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @HireDate,@Birthdate,@Title)

End
GO

Declare @Return int;

 Exec @Return = NewEmployee
 @LastName = 'Beesley',
 @FirstName = 'Pam',
 @HireDate = 'Current Date',
 @BirthDate = '12/30/1972',
 @Title = 'Receptionist';

 Select @Return;
```

And the return is not working because I have not declare the return. My question is what can I do to make this work should I just insert the row or should I use the return?

Comment: What kind of SQL? MySQL? SQL Server? Postgresql?

Comment: Your procedure NewEmployee is returning nothing, what do you want it to return ?

Comment: I need it to return the Last name and stuff that I put in.Such as Besley,Pam, Current Date, 12/30/1972, and the receptionist. I am on Sql Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewEmployee (
     @LastName nvarchar(75)
     ,@FirstName nvarchar(50)
     ,@HireDate datetime
     ,@Birthdate datetime
     ,@Title nvarchar(30))

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Employees (LastName,FirstName,HireDate,BirthDate,Title)
    VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName, @HireDate,@Birthdate,@Title)

End
GO



 Exec NewEmployee
 @LastName = 'Beesley',
 @FirstName = 'Pam',
 @HireDate = 'Current Date',  <-- EDIT : Here you need a real date 
 @BirthDate = '12/30/1972',
 @Title = 'Receptionist';
```

You don't need the return value and everything will be inserted correctly

Comment: Ok I wasnt to sure but thats what I had at first but I keep getting this error Error converting data type varchar to datetime.Which I know that it does with the label of the date Edit: I fixed it.. THanks

Comment: Look at the edit, if your passing "current date", it's sure it's failing, because it's a datetime in your stored proc